# Add Menlo as monospace font for Mac OS 10.6 users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, fonts

Mac OS 10.6 (a.k.a. Snow Leopard) includes a pretty new font called Menlo that supersedes Monaco as the default monospaced font.

I'd like to petition the overflowers to include it right after Consolas in the `font-family` for code on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Before Consolas would be better. That way Mac users will get it first, even if they have Consolas installed, and everyone else will never have to know.

Comment: @Quinn Taylor: As a Mac user in love with Consolas. Please no.

Comment: @Jeff: I just came looking for this post as I noticed that the fonts had changed this morning... looks good! perhaps a bit geneva-like (taller and less broad than the monaco family), but it still looks nice on OSX.

Answer (score 6):

Not a Mac user but I went looking for a preview of the Menlo font.

Here's one:

[image: Menlo vs Sans Mono]

Image source:
http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/06/font-changes-coming-to-mac-os-x-snow-leopard.ars
http://typophile.com/files/menlovsdejavusansmono_6131.png

Update:

Upon seeing more comments on Menlo vs Consolas, I found [this article](http://blog.chalitnc.com/2009/09/20/menlo-vs-consolas/) which compared both. Here's a visual comparison, courtesy of http://blog.chalitnc.com/2009/09/20/menlo-vs-consolas/

[Menlo vs Consolas http://blog.chalitnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/menlo_vs_consolas.jpg](http://blog.chalitnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/menlo_vs_consolas.jpg)

Comment: Give credit http://typophile.com/node/58625

Comment: @jleedev, you got me there. Added :)

Comment: Proven: consolas is magnificent

Answer (score 6):

I think that Menlo should probably be placed *before* Consolas. The reasoning I have here is that many of us who are using the Trilogy from Macs probably have Microsoft Office installed -- and if we have 2008, we have the Microsoft "C" fonts.

Consolas does, admittedly, look really good on a Mac (I use it in XCode; I wasn't even aware that I got this new Menlo font when I upgraded until just now), but if you really want to give Mac users the best Mac experience, I would consider putting Menlo before Consolas in the chain, as it is highly unlikely that any Windows or Linux user will have it.

Comment: Consolas is THE BEST! THE **BEST!** http://goo.gl/G30L

Comment: Consolas is the BESTEST!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love me some Consolas. But other Mac users may disagree with me and prefer Menlo. I'm looking out for their best interests. :) Also ... I thought we frowned on URL shorteners around these parts. ;-)

Comment: jeff is in the frowning exception list :P